# How to add a package to a flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add this package to my flutter project in Visual Code.

```
import 'package:flutter_samples/fetch_data/photo.dart';

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  html: ^0.14.0+3
  photo:
```

I've tried to search for 'photo' on this site, [Dart Packages](https://pub.dev/), but I can't find it.

Is there a way to search for it through the flutter command line?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you're doing it in a wrong way.

Flutter projects can be added in pubspec.yaml file.

You're importing it, not adding package.

Before you can import a package, you have to add a package to pubspec.yaml

Please refer this.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I added it to my yaml file, but it just says it can't find it. I edited my question to include that bit.

Comment: You've to add it like this
photo: ^0.4.5

You've to mention the version number.
If you're not aware about version number you can include a package like this

 photo: any

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for [photo: ^0.4.5 package find here](https://pub.dev/packages/photo#-installing-tab-),

> in addition, you don't have to import any dependencies like classes.

[image]